# How to make an array of arrays in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an array of userIDs, which contains specific users from a certain group.

{userID1,userID2}

```
val userIDArrayList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
    userIDArrayList.add(userID1)
    userIDArrayList.add(userID2)
```

I want to make a master array which contains several different user arrays.

[{userID1, userID2}, {userID3, userID4}]

How can I do that in kotlin?

Comment: Just one note, these are `List`s not `Array`s. It's called `ArrayList` because it's a list implemented with arrays, but it's not equivalent to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
mutableListOf(mutableListOf("yourobject"),mutableListOf("yourobject"))
```

or

```
val myList = mutableListOf<MutableList<yourobject>>()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, declare the master array which will contains other arrays

```kotlin
    val masterList = mutableListOf<List<String>>()
```

Secondly, declare the arrays which will be nested. Assuming userID1, userID2, userID3, userID4 are declared somewhere

```kotlin
    val subList1 = listOf(userID1,userID2)
    val subList2 = listOf(userID3,userID4)
```

Finally, add the sublists to the master

```kotlin
    masterList.add(subList1)
    masterList.add(subList2)
```

Of course you can do all of this with only one line during masterList instantiation

```kotlin
    val masterList = mutableListOf<List<String>>(
        listOf(userID1,userID2),
        listOf(userID3,userID4)
    )
```

Comment: Can we send the mutable list via an intent to another activity?